# Is there a way to animate a sprite position and rotation related to its own transform in Unity2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a 2D top-down game where you get to use a variety of weapons, its combat is like a fusion between Castlevania Aria of Sorrow and Zelda: Minish Cap.

So, when the attack button is pressed, my code spawns the weapon object into the scene, which plays the attack animation and then is destroyed. The problem is that I made an animation that covers an arc below the character, which is ok, but I need to make so that this animation plays sideways or upwards when the character is facing these directions.

The problem is that the animation always plays the same downwards version because its keyframes rotation and position are related to the transform of the player, doesn't matter what direction or position I spawn the weapon in.

How can I make the animation play in the direction I need?

The weapon spawning code:

```
private float hitRotation;

public void Update()
    {
        float lastMoveX = characterAnimator.GetFloat("lastMoveX");
        float lastMoveY = characterAnimator.GetFloat("lastMoveY");

        if (lastMoveX == 0 && lastMoveY == -1)
        {
            hitRotation = 0f;
        }
        else if (lastMoveX == 1 && lastMoveY == 0)
        {
            hitRotation = 90f;
        }
        else if (lastMoveX == 0 && lastMoveY == 1)
        {
            hitRotation = 180f;
        }
        else if (lastMoveX == -1 && lastMoveY == 0)
        {
            hitRotation = 270f;
        }

        Debug.Log(hitRotation);
    }
    public void Attack()
    {
        
        if (equippedWeapon != null)
        {
            GameObject instantiatedWeapon = Instantiate(weapons.Find(obj=>obj.name == equippedWeaponName), transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, hitRotation), transform);
            equippedWeapon.Attack();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No weapon equipped");
        }
    }
```

I was hoping to see the weapon performing the arc animation on one of those 4 directions (without having to code the movement), but it always plays the same version I animated